# Alpine3 js & Larvavel

Tags: laravel, alpine-linux, alpine.js

I'm having some issues trying to get the following code to work.
I'm sure I'm over looking something simple but cannot spot it

My code is bringing up the error: Alpine Expression Error: unexpected token: string literal

```
<div 
    x-data="{ images: ['background-1.jpg', 'background-2.jpg'], index: 0}"
    x-init="index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)">

    <div :style="'background-image: url(/img/' + $images[index]')'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a mixed PHP-JS syntax. JS don't require the dollar sign prefix for variables (only if you added them originally).

The corrected syntax (with extra single quotation marks around the image URL):

```
<div :style="'background-image: url(\'/img/' + images[index] + '\')'"></div>
```

Or we can use the [JS template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as well with backtics (`) which is IMO more readable:

```
<div :style="`background-image: url('/img/${images[index]}')`"></div>
```